# Concat two html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
var bread =  $('<li/>').html($('<a/>',{
    href: '#',
    text: 'Alle',
    click: function(){ Diagnose.start() } 
}));
bread += $('<li/>').html($('<a/>',{
    href: '#',
    text: data['icd1'].nummer,
    click: function(){ Diagnose.icd(2,data['icd1'].id) } 
}));

$('#side-panel2 .breadcrumb').html(bread.toString());
```

The problem is that the ouput is not the html i would like to have but instead its:

```
<ul class="breadcrumb" style="margin-top: 9px;margin-bottom: 0px;font-size:11px">
 [object Object][object Object]
 .....
```

First my code looked like this:

```
$('#side-panel2 .breadcrumb').html($('<li/>').html($('<a/>',{
    href: '#',
    text: 'Alle',
    click: function(){ Diagnose.start() } 
})));                                   
$('#side-panel2 .breadcrumb').append($('<li/>').html($('<a/>',{
    href: '#',
    text: data['icd1'].nummer,
    click: function(){ Diagnose.icd(2,data['icd1'].id) } 
})));
```

This solution worked but i would like to change the html in one step because with the code from above a little delay can be seen! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [.add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) - not a concatenation operator because those are jQuery objects not strings

```
var bread =  $('<li/>').html($('<a/>',{href: '#',text: 'Alle',click: function(){Diagnose.start()} }));
bread = bread.add($('<li/>').html($('<a/>',{href: '#',text: data['icd1'].nummer,click: function(){Diagnose.icd(2,data['icd1'].id)} })));

$('#side-panel2 .breadcrumb').empty().append(bread);
```

Comment: Now i'm curious, why `empty().append()` and not instead `.html()`? I mean, any reason?

Comment: @A.Wolff just the as per the api of [.html()](.html( htmlString )) says htmlString... so I personally doesn't like to pass a object to it that is it

Comment: Well that's quite a good reason but indeed, DOC should be updated then. Anyway, thank you Arun!

Answer (score 3):

In short, in general:

```
$(".container").append( $("<a>A</a>"), $("<a>B</a>") );
```

Take a look on this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/R4j7Q/1/).