# How to concatenate two htmlelements?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have 2 similar HTML table classes, I call them as *htmlelement* and want to **concatenate** them.
It is similar to my code:

```
var first = document.getElementsByClassName("firstclass") as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>;
var second = document.getElementsByClassName("secondclass") as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>;

for(var i=0;i<secondclass.length;i++){
    firstclass.appendChild(secondclass.item(i));
}
```

But it does not work. `Concat` function does not work either.

This is similar to one class.

```
<body>
  <tr class="first">
    <td id="one_{{i}}" class="col" (change)="typeAdd()"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    </td>
    <td id="second_{{i}}" class="col"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: `firstclass` and `secondclass` are not defined in your example. Please be more specific about what "does not work". Are you getting an error?

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096680/concat-two-html-elements

Comment: they are html table classes

Comment: I have no idea what result you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

Just use array destructor to do that, see [**destructuring assignment**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for more infos.

And append the elements to the target parent

```js
var first  = document.getElementsByClassName("firstclass"), 
    second = document.getElementsByClassName("secondclass"),
    containerElement = document.querySelector("#some-container"),
    both = [...first, ...second];
both.forEach(e => containerElement.appendChild(e));
```

```css
#some-container {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="some-container"></div>
<p class="firstclass">first class 1</p>
<p class="firstclass">first class 2</p>
<p class="firstclass">first class 3</p>
<p class="secondclass">second class 1</p>
<p class="secondclass">second class 2</p>
<p class="secondclass">second class 3</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="c1">a1</div>
        <div class="c1">a2</div>
        <div class="c1">a3</div>
        <div class="c2">b1</div>
        <div class="c2">b2</div>
        <div class="c2">b3</div>
        <script>
            c1s = document.querySelectorAll('.c1');
            c2s = document.querySelectorAll('.c2');
            c1s.forEach((element, index) => {
                element.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', c2s[index]);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

will produce:

```html
<div class="c1">a1</div>
<div class="c2">b1</div>
<div class="c1">a2</div>
<div class="c2">b2</div>
<div class="c1">a3</div>
<div class="c2">b3</div>
```

I think this is what you need.